# About threads in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a button click which contains some ten methods. Here I want to use threads in the button click or some where in the code so that my windows form application will not hang.

This what I have tried so far...!!

```
                collectListOfPTags();

                REqDocCheck = new Thread(new ThreadStart(collectListOfPTags));

                REqDocCheck.IsBackground = true;

                REqDocCheck.Start();

                WaitHandle[] AWait = new WaitHandle[] { new AutoResetEvent(false) };
                while (REqDocCheck.IsAlive)
                {
                    WaitHandle.WaitAny(AWait, 50, false);
                    System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
                }
```

In the method `collectionListOfPtags()` am getting an exception which says "a combobox is accessed from the thread other than it was created on"

Thank's for the patience..
Any help will be appreciated..

Comment: There's an excellent intro to threading here: [`Albahari`](http://www.albahari.com/threading/)

Comment: You cannot access a gui control from another thread other than the main thread. There are 19861353 Posts on SO about that...search for it (http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=gui+thread)

Comment: @NicholasButler I have gone through that..!! Thanks for reply

Comment: ok :) Look at `BackgroundWorker` then - it was designed for this situation.

Comment: @NicholasButler even though thats true, it will not fix the actual thread problem accessing a gui control

Comment: `BeginInvoke` is a keyword

Comment: @derape It depends on what `collectListOfPTags()` does - `BackgorundWorker` marshals the `ProgressChanged` and `RunWorkerCompleted` events back to the UI thread for you.

Comment: @NicholasButler collectionListOfPtags() collects all strings from text file and do some changes and put them in a combo box. That list may be some 1000 strings..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a good fit for the `BackgroundWorker` component.

Split your `collectListOfPTags` method into 2 methods - the first collects and processes the data and the second updates the UI controls.

Something like this:

```
void OnClick( ... )
{
  var results = new List<string>();

  var bw = new BackgroundWorker();

  bw.DoWork += ( s, e ) => CollectData( results );
  bw.RunWorkerCompleted += ( s, e ) => UpdateUI( results );

  bw.RunWorkerAsync();
}

void CollectData( List<string> results )
{
  ... build strings and add them to the results list
}

void UpdateUI( List<string> results )
{
  ... update the ComboBox from the results
}
```

The `BackgroundWorker` will run `CollectData` in the background on a thread pool thread, but will run `UpdateUI` on the UI thread so you can access the `ComboBox` correctly.

Answer (score 0):

What you need here is a delegate! You simply need to create a delegate and put it in the function which accesses GUI from thread function.

```
public delegate void DemoDelegate();
```

In your code,

```
collectionListOfPtags()
{
    if ((this.InvokeRequired)) {
    this.Invoke(new DemoDelegate(collectionListOfPtags));
    return;
    }

     // Your Code HERE
}
```

I hope this will work!  Good Luck :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at threadpools?  A thread pool is a collection of threads that can be used to perform several tasks in the background. They are simple of use and thread safe.

Here's an (really simple) example : 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h4732ks0.aspx